# Empty arrays and collections should be returned instead of null (java:S1168)

Tags: java, collections, set, sonarlint-eclipse

As I installed SonarLint plugin in my eclipse IDE, i got the above
(Heading) Major Issue.

Let's Assume:

```
public List<CountryModel> getAllCountries() { 
    return null;        //***SonarLint Suggesest*: return an empty Collection instead of null.**
}
```

Can be modified (fixed) as below:

```
public List<CountryModel> getAllCountries() {
    return Collections.emptyList();
}
```

Note: Similarly, I have a **Set of CountryModel** as below, and I tried to `return Collections.emptyList();`

```
 public Set<CountryModel> getAllCountries() {
     return Collections.emptyList();
 }
```

I got Exception saying :

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from
List<Object> to Set<CountryModel>.
```

Also Suggested saying, converting `Set` to `List<Object>`.

So how to resolve this issue **if I need Set, to Return an empty Collection and not null or nor conversion to `List<Object>` ?

Comment: You can use `Collections.emptySet()`

Answer (score 0):

Use `Collections.emptySet()` instead of `Collections.emptyList()`.

```
 public Set<CountryModel> getAllCountries() {
     return Collections.emptySet();
 }
```

For more information, read the [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#emptySet()).